# Stop fixed width text to column from trimming values

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to stop Excel from deleting spaces at the end of splitted fixed width delimited cells.

I have a string: `AB   123.00  CD`

I have the code:

```
Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, Textqualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(5, 2), Array(13, 2)) _
    , TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

I want the result to be three columns (* represents spaces for ease of reading):

```
1. AB***
2. 123.00**
3. CD
```

The outcome that I am currently experiencing:

```
1. AB
2. 123.00
3. CD
```

I don't know how to stop the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if there is a way to achieve what you are wanting, but a work around would be to loop through the cells and format the data accordingly, something like below, which will loop through column A & B and add the number of respective spaces you desire:

```
Sub foo()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        OldVal = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        NewVal = Left(OldVal & "     ", 5)
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = NewVal

        OldVal2 = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        NewVal2 = Left(OldVal2 & "        ", 8)
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = NewVal2
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about that as well, but this is an annoying work around to be honest. Might have to do it though. The problem is that I want to check whether the input file has the right format and that way I wouldn't know for certain.

Comment: @Spurious you could check the contents of the text file without loading it into Excel, and as it is supposed to be fixed length, you could achieve this by checking the length of each line in the file...?

Comment: Xabier, firstly, I appreciate your help. This would be another way of doing it, I originally wanted to get it done the easy way, which doesn't seem to work. Another idea I had was to concatenate the string again using your method with `Left(val, x)` and then comparing the strings. This would help me know that indeed everything was put together accordingly.